# How to use external dependencies in a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Google Cloud Function and have zero knowledge of cloud computing in general. I have been trying to figure out how to import and use external dependencies (let's say [RestClient](https://nuget.org/packages/RestClient.Net/) or [Newtonsoft's Json library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for C#) in Google Cloud Function (I have also been instructed to code with Google Cloud Shell).

In Visual Studio, we would use Nuget to manage external libraries. How do I install or import external libraries so that I could use them in my Google Cloud Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define them in the `*.csproj` file (or add them with an IDE).
[Specifying dependencies in .NET](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-dotnet) provides an example for that.
As usual, one needs to know the package name and it's version.

I'd suggest to learn from an IDE, how it edits the `*.csproj` file -
then you'll know exactly what to manually type/paste into there.

The [`dotnet add package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package) CLI command does merely the same;
it's basically all about adding a new line into the `*.csproj` file.

```
dotnet add package RestClient.Net --version 5.1.0
```

One can not only use Nuget from the GUI, but also in PowerShell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-install-package

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comparing the versions of the `*.csproj` file before and after, will show you the edits it made.
Even without [`dotnet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) or [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) CLI installed, one can always manually edit the `*.csproj` file.

Comment: Thank you for the precise answer. I wish I could upvote the answer but I need 8 more reputations haha.